# Android: how can you tell that a View has become Visible?

Tags: android, android-view

I have a FrameView containing a full-screen ImageView on top and a full-screen SurfaceView underneath. The ImageView starts out INVISIBLE while I display the SurfaceView. Now I set the ImageView to VISIBLE and want to update what is on the SurfaceView, unseen.

But the ImageView is not yet really visible. I have to wait until the ImageView is actually visible before messing with the SurfaceView. How is this done?

The only way I found was to wait 50ms (nothing less would do) before messing with the SurfaceView. Which happens to work reliably on my device, but is obviously a hack.

To be more specific: on the SurfaceView I am preparing a movie. Which makes the screen go black. I am trying to avoid the black by covering it with an image.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onVisibilityChanged%28android.view.View,%20int%29 ?

Comment: I tried using an ImageView to "hide" the blackness while prepping a movie at one point but as I recall the device still shows black during this time. Even if you have something displayed "on top" of the Video Surface.

Comment: Is it not possible to hide the video surface view by calling its ID using findviewbyid?

Comment: Tim: the image hides the preparing video just fine if I wait 50ms after setting its visibility to VISIBLE before preparing the video.

Answer (score 2):

You can use View.onVisibilityChanged().

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work for me. Overrode this function, put the call to prepare the movie in there, still got black. According to the log, the function was called instantly after I did setVisibility(). So the image was not yet visible.